# Have user select contacts from HTML form?

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile

Is it possible to have a control in a standard webpage that prompts a user on a mobile device to select a contact? I have a simple SPA that I would like users to be able to invite their friends to use. Rather than having them type in the names/numbers manually I'd like them to be able to select them from their contacts list directly. I don't need access to the whole list, just whichever ones the user selects, so it doesn't seem like there should be a security issues.

Edit: In that other question someone suggested using an API called BridgeIt, but that API has been discontinued. Someone suggested that the functionality of that API was available in HTML5 now, but didn’t explain further. Does anyone know if this is possible with HTML5 or if there is an alternative to BridgeIt available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a website (HTML5,JavaScript) access a mobile device's (android/iPhone) contact list, SDCard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076800/can-a-website-html5-javascript-access-a-mobile-devices-android-iphone-conta)

Comment: I saw that one. The best answer there suggests an API called BridgeIt, but then a user points out below that BridgeIt was shut down because the functionality is available in HTML5. That’s what I'm looking for... how to do it in HTML5.