# Upload contacts from my phone into a Django app - No other answer solved it

Tags: ios, django, iphone, contacts

I am creating a django app and one of the functionalities I would like to add is that, if I want, I can upload into my app contacts that I have on my iphone.

Basically the flow I would like to create is that if a user lands on the page on it's mobile phone and click on "upload", the app opens the user's contact list and the use can select the contact or contacts he would like to upload.

How can I do it?

Comment: As far as I know web sites (I’m guessing your Django app is a web site?) can’t access iOS contacts. More details at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076800/can-a-website-html5-javascript-access-a-mobile-devices-android-iphone-conta#27460671). “How can I do it?” – you can’t.

Comment: Got it. I was hoping that response to be obsolete (2013) but I guess no progress have been made